# Is this Multiple Sources Multiple Destinations algorithm NP hard?

Tags: algorithm

I have a map of a city (2D) and random points throughout the city. Some of these random points are places were tourists can be dropped off. From those drop off points, I need to color all other points that the tourists cannot reach within X length (say miles) from the previously visited point. So points from the dropoff can be chained as long as they are close enough through each hop within X distance. Again, all random sources and destinations, so there is no established direction graph.

But, I feel it may be NP-Hard. Is this correct?

I don't want just the shortest path, so I feel like that eliminates Dijkstra and some of the different graph algo options I can use.

A brute force BFS search with various pruning does not go far obviously. Generating all the potential neighbors simply is too complex past a certain number of random points. I was considering Floyd–Warshall or some variant, and flag points as not touchable from my sources as it goes, but because the points do not have connections to each other, this too will take a significant amount of time and memory to compute all possible neighbors for each relevant node.

Am I over-complicating the complexity? Perhaps inverting the problem somehow may help - traversing from all the random nodes to the source nodes as "destinations"?

Comment: So long as there are no negative weight edges, Dijkstra's should work just fine; you need to run it for all sources, though. An interesting twist is that it appears you cannot visit a node if its distance is too far away, which really means that an edge you're given is invalid and should not be considered for this search.

Comment: I thought it would, but there are no edges to start with. They have to be generated. When there are thousands of potential edges, it adds up quickly. I'm wondering if there is some kind of variance that be used.

Comment: There are at most n(n-1)/2 edges in any simple graph of n vertices. That's not much. At least not that much to call it NP-hard.

Comment: @JuanLopes The number of vertices doesn't really tell you whether a problem is NP-hard. After all, there are only `(n^2 - n)/2` verticies in the traveling salesman problem, and it's NP-hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*see below for an optimization*

I think you're over-complicating things. The brute force method would compare every point against every other. The worst case is O(r*(s+r)) where r is the number of random points, and s is the number of start points.

You can use queues to reduce the complexity in the expected case, where all (or most) points are reachable. The idea is that once you've determined that a point is reachable, you never again have to check whether it's reachable from other points. You do, however, have to check if other points are reachable from it.

When you start, all of your random points are "in the unknown." That is, they've never been visited. But once a point is visited, it's no longer unknown: we know that it can be reached. So when you visit a point the first time, you move it from the unknown to the frontier. And you go through the frontier, looking for points in the unknown that are within reach.

The general idea is:

```
unknown = list of random points
frontier = new queue()
add all source cells to frontier
while (!unknown.isEmpty() && !frontier.isEmpty())
{
    point = frontier.dequeue()
    for each unknown_point
    {
        if (dist(point, unknown_point) < distance)
        {
            remove unknown_point from unknown list,
            and add to frontier queue
        }
    }
}

if (!unknown.IsEmpty())
{
    // there are still points in the unknown,
    // which means that not all points are reachable.
}
```

At worst, this algorithm will test every starting point against every random point, and every random point against every other random point, so the complexity is O(r*(s + r)), where r is the number of random points and s is the number of starting points. Understand, though, that the worst case will appear only in a very sparse graph, or when large clumps of points are unreachable.

Note that "remove unknown_point from unknown list" can itself be an O(r) operation if `unknown` is a common list data structure or array. A useful optimization would be to make `unknown` a queue, and modify your inner loop like this:

```
    point = frontier.dequeue()
    unknown_count = unknown.count()
    while (unknown_count > 0)
    {
        unknown_point = unknown.dequeue()
        --unknown_count
        if (dist(point, unknown_point) < distance)
        {
            // within range, add to frontier
            frontier.enqueue(unknown_point)
        }
        else
        {
            // not reachable. Put it back in the unknown.
            unqnown.enqueue(unknown_point)
        }
    }
```

### Optimization

You can reduce complexity in the expected case by incorporating the "binning" optimization recommended by Peter de Rivaz. This limits the number of points you have to examine for each frontier point by restricting the search to adjacent bins: the only place where unknown points could possibly be in reach. Basically, you create grid to cover all of your random points. Something like:

```
       0        1        2        3        4        5
   -------------------------------------------------------
   |  ..    |        | .  .   |        |        |        |
A  |   . .  |        |  .  .  |  .     |        |  . .   |
   |  .     |        |    .   | .   .  |        |   .    |
   -------------------------------------------------------
   |        | .     .|        |  . . . |        |.       |
B  |        | .      |    .   | .  .   |        |        |
   |        |      . |        |   .    |        |       .|
   -------------------------------------------------------
   | .   .  |        |   .    |        |        | .      |
C  |   .    |        | .      |        |        |   .    |
   |        |        |     .  |        |        |   .    |
   -------------------------------------------------------
   |    .   |        | .  .   |  .     |   . .  | .  .   |
D  |        |        |   .    |    .   |   .    | . . .  |
   |     .  |        |     .  |        |     .  |  .     |
   -------------------------------------------------------
   |        |.   .   |  .   . |        |        |        |
E  |        |  .     |    .   |        |        |        |
   |        |     .  |  .  .  |        |        |        |
   -------------------------------------------------------
   |        |     .  |        | .  .   |  .  .  |  .  .  |
F  |        |  .     |        |  .  .  | .  .   | .  .   |
   |        | .  .   |        |   .    |      . |      . |
   -------------------------------------------------------
```

If your distance threshhold is `dist`, then each of those grid squares is `dist` units on each side.

We know, then, that a point in grid B3 can be within `dist` units of points only in the nine adjacent squares. So we don't have to test against points in, say, grid F5. Note that not all points in A3 will necessarily be reachable from a point in B3, but they *could be*. In fact, we can't guarantee that every point in B3 will be adjacent to every other point in B3. Consider a grid that contains only two points: one at the extreme upper-left and one at the extreme lower-right. The distance between those two points will be more than `dist`.

Depending on the density of your points, you might want a sparse data structure of some kind for the bins.

The first thing you do is bin the random points. Make a pass through the random points to find the topmost and leftmost coordinates. That becomes your origin point. Bin A0's top-left corner is at (topmost, leftmost). You can then go through all the random points and add them to bins.

After that, the algorithm focuses on the bins, rather than on the random points array:

```
frontier = new queue()
add source points to frontier
while (!allBinsAreEmpty() && !frontier.IsEmpty())
{
    point = frontier.dequeue()
    sourceBin = determine bin that point is in
    adjacentBins = getAdjacentBins(sourceBin.x, sourceBin.y)
    for each adjacent bin
    {
        for each binPoint in bin
        {
            if distance(point, binPoint) <= dist
            {
                frontier.enqueue(binPoint)
                bin.Remove(binPoint)
            }
        }
        if (bin is empty)
            remove bin
    }
}
if (!allBinsAreEmpty())
{
    // there are unreachable points
}
```

Getting the adjacent bins is pretty easy:

```
getAdjacentBins(binx, biny)
{
    adjacentBins[] = [bins[binx, biny]]
    if (bins[binx-1, biny-1] != null) adjacentBins += bin[binx-1, biny-1]
    if (bins[binx-1, biny] != null) adjacentBins += bin[binx-1, biny]
    if (bins[binx-1, biny+1] != null) adjacentBins += bin[binx-1, biny+1]
    if (bins[binx, biny+1] != null) adjacentBins += bin[binx, biny+1]
    ....
    return adjacentBins
}
```

Comment: I see you updated your answer, I was going to respond by saying that I tried an inplace method of tagging unknown/known points (as opposed to the queues, but effectively still the same), but that still wasn't fast enough. I'll check out the adjacent bins suggestion, I was originally confused how the bins would be constructed, but you cleared that up.

Comment: @user999999928: In-place tagging still requires that you look at every point for every other point to see if it's already been tagged. You don't have to do the distance calculation every time, but you still have to look at the point. The queues will, in the expected case, be more efficient. But, yeah ... the bins should be much better.

Comment: The optimizations makes more sense. I haven't attempted this yet, but is there a particular reason to use your proposed 2D setup for the bins (X and Y keys) versus 1 key (X&Y hashed somehow)? I've been reading up on different kinds of binning but I don't know when you'd use one instead of the other.

I also read that depending on how packed the random points are from each other (or far apart), despite the constant X units apart we're looking for, we'd want tighter bin distances. Is that related to the 2D binning?

Comment: The bins are in a 2D grid, so that's how I refer to them. How your code hashes the keys is an implementation detail. If you use an array to srore the bins, you'd use the two coordinates. If you're using a sparse data structure, you'd use some kind of hash. However you implement it shouldn't materially affect the running time. As I said, if your points are sparse--lots of empty bins--use a sparse data structure.  Otherwise use an array.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a grid of square buckets of width R*R where R is the constant distance you are given.

Place all the points into these buckets, then you can very quickly answer queries of the form "Find all points within a distance R of my current point" by simply checking the 3*3 array of buckets centred on that point.

You can then use BFS to colour all the points within range of your source points, but it should be much faster as the buckets should mean that you need to consider many fewer potential neighbours at each stage.

(Incidentally, your original approaches are also polynomial time so this problem is not NP-hard.)

Comment: Is there a name of this? That seems like a good way to iteratively generate neighbors but what do you mean "place all these points into these buckets"?

Comment: For example, suppose we implement this by having a linked list for each bucket.  When you place a point in the bucket, it means to add the point to the linked list for that location.